# Managing alerts across multiple sites-sub-sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm wondering if MS has figured out a way for a user to manage ALL of their Alerts across all sites/sub-sites without having to go into each site to do so.
I don't understand why in 'almost' 2019 this can't be done easily yet.
If there's something within the system that I just can't find, please let me know.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no way to manage all alerts across all sites by OOB method in SharePoint online.

Then we can manage the alerts by PowerShell in SharePoint online.

More references:

[Creating SharePoint alerts via CSOM.](http://www.cornflowerdesign.co.uk/2017/08/creating-sharepoint-alerts-via-csom/)

[SharePoint Online: Delete Alerts using PowerShell.](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/10/sharepoint-online-delete-alerts-using-powershell.html)

[How to Disable/Enable User Alerts in SharePoint Office 365 using CSOM PowerShell.](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-DisableEnable-User-Alerts-in-SharePoint-Office-365-using-CSOM-PowerShell)

[SharePoint Online: Using PowerShell to delete alerts in site/sub sites using CSOM.](https://sharepointpixels.wordpress.com/2018/09/14/sharepoint-online-using-powershell-to-delete-alerts-in-site-sub-sites-using-csom/)